# Error : 'calculate_intervals' is not an exported object from 'namespace:forecastML'

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to run the following code.

```
data_combined_r_valid <- forecastML::calculate_intervals(data_combined_r, data_residuals_valid, levels = c(.50, .80, .95), times = 100L)
```

I get an error :

> 'calculate_intervals' is not an exported object from 'namespace:forecastML'

Can anyone please suggest to me if there is any alternative for calculate_intervals or give an explanation as to why it isn't working in this line of code.

Link: https://github.com/nredell/forecastML/blob/master/notebooks/python_sklearn_and_r_in_parallel/Forecasting%20with%20Python%20-%20scikit%20learn%20in%20parallel.ipynb

Answer (score 4):

`calculate_intervals` first came to exist on [May 24, 2020](https://github.com/nredell/forecastML/commits/master/R/calculate_intervals.R) (see the history). The version of the forecastML package on CRAN is dated [May 7, 2020](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecastML/forecastML.pdf) and does not list that function, suggesting that it does not have it. Your best bet is to either figure out how to [install a development version of forecastML](https://github.com/nredell/forecastML#install) or complain to the author of what you're reading.